# How can I use certreq.exe to sign a CSR while providing a CertificateTemplate and SAN attributes?

Tags: powershell, syntax, automation, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

Welcome everyone!

I am currently trying to automate strictly internal SSL-Certificate signing using Powershell and `certreq.exe`. At this point I am able to create valid certificates but the `-attrib` option is causing me some headache.

I send my automatically created CSR to my CA and i get a valid cert but it's missing the first 3 SAN entries `IPAddress=$iLOIP&DNS=$iLOIP&DNS=$hostname`. However the last one (`DNS=iLOFQDN`) is present. I I am using this exact command:

```
certreq.exe -submit -config $certificateserver -attrib "CertificateTemplate:$certificatetemplate\nsan:IPAddress=$iLOIP&DNS=$iLOIP&DNS=$hostname&DNS=$iLOFQDN" "$scriptpath\currentcsr.txt" "$scriptpath\currentcert.cer"
```

I am not sure about the syntax and the weird thing is that it doesn't work without the `\n` between the `CertificateTemplate:$certificatetemplate` and `SAN:`. I found that out earlier when googling the problem but it does not fix everything for me.

**Unfortunately, there is no way for me to use an .inf file, where I would be able to enter the SAN entries.**

Now to my question(s):
What is the correct syntax to be used inside the `-attrib` field?
Is it possible somehow not specify a template? Am I over-complicating things drastically and there is already a tool to do this all?

Comment: I don't follow your request. certreq uses the CSR for that request process as the signing part. This is not really a PowerShell code issue. The command you are showing would be identical in a .bat/.cmd/.vbs file.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment, here is a prebuilt PowerShell script to request SAN certs.

[powershell request a SAN cert](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20request%20a%20SAN%20cert&form=ANNTH1&refig=6f441565eb35432b92a6ae14963fa041&sp=-1&pq=powershell%20request%20a%20san%20c&sc=3-26&qs=n&sk=&cvid=6f441565eb35432b92a6ae14963fa041)

> [Certificate with SAN using Powershell - with Import/Export](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Certificate-with-SAN-using-37a4cbd6)
>
> This script uses powershell to create a certificate with SAN (Subject
> Alternative Name[s]), submit the request to the CA with specific web
> server template and issue to a server/ workstation accordingly.
> Updated to allow for wildcard CNs.
>
> [Download: New-CACertificate.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Certificate-with-SAN-using-37a4cbd6/file/193072/1/New-CACertificate.ps1)

```
<# 
 
.SYNOPSIS 
Script to ease the pain of creating/submitting/automating the process of creating a certificate for on-prem CA 
 
.DESCRIPTION 
Required Variables: Subject, Exportable, SAN1, Template. Up to 5 SANs can be included in this script. More can be added if desired. User must have privileges to submit / create certificate template.  
 
.EXAMPLE 
./get-certificate-inf.ps1 -Subject contoso.com -Exportable $false -Template Server -SAN1 contoso.com -SAN2 www.contoso.com -SAN3 devsite.constoso.com 
 
.NOTES 
Variables that Require user modification to the script: See "Subject Variables" Section. 
 
#> 
 
 
[CmdletBinding()] 
Param( 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] 
[string]$Subject, 
 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] 
[string]$Exportable, 
 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] 
[string]$SAN1, 
 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)] 
[string]$SAN2, 
 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)] 
[string]$SAN3, 
 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)] 
[string]$SAN4, 
 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)] 
[string]$SAN5, 
 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] 
[string]$Template 
 
) 
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Inquire' 
 
## Gathering Logic for SAN 
$SAN = '' 
if ($SAN2) 
{ 
    $SAN +="&dns=$SAN2" 
} 
else{} 
 
if ($SAN3) 
{ 
    $SAN +="&dns=$SAN3" 
} 
else{} 
 
if ($SAN4) 
{ 
    $SAN +="&dns=$SAN4" 
} 
else{} 
 
if ($SAN5) 
{ 
    $SAN +="&dns=$SAN5" 
} 
else{} 
 
$FullSAN ="{text}dns=$SAN1$SAN" 
 
## Required Because Powershell interprets $Windows as a variable not a string 
$Windows = '$Windows' 
 
$inputfiletemplate = @" 
[Version]  
Signature="$Windows NT$" 
 
##Enter Subject Variables Here and uncomment: 
# $O = [organization] 
# $OU = [Organizational Unit] 
# $E = [email] 
# $L = [locality] 
# $ST = [state] 
# $C = [country] 
 
[NewRequest]  
Subject = "CN=$Subject, O=$O, OU=$OU, E=$E, L=$L, ST=$ST, C=$C"   ; For a wildcard use "CN=*.CONTOSO.COM" for example 
Exportable = $Exportable                  ; Private key is not exportable  
KeyLength = 2048                    ; Common key sizes: 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384  
KeySpec = 1                         ; AT_KEYEXCHANGE  
KeyUsage = 0xA0                     ; Digital Signature, Key Encipherment  
MachineKeySet = True                ; The key belongs to the local computer account  
ProviderName = "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider"  
ProviderType = 12  
SMIME = FALSE  
RequestType = CMC 
 
; At least certreq.exe shipping with Windows Vista/Server 2008 is required to interpret the [Strings] and [Extensions] sections below 
 
[Strings]  
szOID_SUBJECT_ALT_NAME2 = "2.5.29.17"  
szOID_ENHANCED_KEY_USAGE = "2.5.29.37"  
szOID_PKIX_KP_SERVER_AUTH = "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"  
szOID_PKIX_KP_CLIENT_AUTH = "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2" 
 
[Extensions]  
%szOID_SUBJECT_ALT_NAME2% = "$FullSAN"  
%szOID_ENHANCED_KEY_USAGE% = "{text}%szOID_PKIX_KP_SERVER_AUTH%,%szOID_PKIX_KP_CLIENT_AUTH%" 
 
[RequestAttributes]  
CertificateTemplate=$Template 
"@ 
 
### Gathering Certificate information ### 
 
$filename = $Subject.Substring(0,3) 
 
### Make allowance for wildcard CNs 
 
    if ($filename -like "*") 
        { 
            Write-Host "Hang on...have to create a new filename..." 
            $filename = (-join ((65..90) + (97..122) | Get-Random -Count 5 | % {[char]$_})) 
        } 
        else  
        { 
        #Do Nothing     
        } 
 
$inputfiletemplate | Out-File "$filename.inf" 
 
Write-Host "Generating request" 
 
### End of Gathering Certificate information ### 
 
# Using Certreq to request a new certificate with information file and request 
& "C:\Windows\System32\certreq.exe" "-new" "$filename.inf" "$filename.req" 
 
# Submitting Request to CA with request and saving file as a .cer 
Write-Host "Submitting request to CA" 
& "C:\Windows\System32\certreq.exe" "-submit" "$filename.req" "$filename.cer" 
 
# Accepting the certificate from SubCA 
& "C:\Windows\System32\certreq.exe" "-accept" "$filename.cer" 
Write-Host "Certificate Imported Successfully" 
 
# File cleanup 
Write-Host "Cleaning up files generated" 
Remove-Item "$filename.*" -Force 
 
# Asking if you would like to export the certificate  
if ($Exportable -eq $TRUE) 
{ 
    if((Read-Host -Prompt "Do you want to export the certificate? Y\N") -eq "y"){ 
#Show certifiate store  
Write-Host "Fetching Certificates in store for you..." 
get-childitem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\my | Format-list subject,thumbprint 
 
#Ask user to copy thumbprint to console 
Write-Host "Please copy the thumbprint to export" 
$thumbprint = Read-Host -Prompt "Please paste the desired thumbprint here" 
 
#Export certificate with password 
get-childitem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\my\$thumbprint | Export-PfxCertificate -Password (read-host -Prompt "Please type your password" -AsSecureString) -ChainOption EndEntityCertOnly -NoClobber -FilePath (read-host -Prompt "Give the PFX a filename with .pfx") 
"`nExport Successful... 'till next time." 
    } 
} 
else 
{ 
    "Mission Complete!" 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and commenting but as I have **boldly** mentioned above, creating the CSR from an .inf file, which your code snippet does, will not work for this case. The CSRs are created by the HPE iLO and Dell iDRAC server management software, which is why I need to use certreq the way I do.

Comment: OK, that last bit of clarification [HPE iLO and Dell iDRAC]. I've never used these so, no field experience, so these [$iLOIP&DNS=$iLOIP&DNS=$hostname] variable name taxonomy, were chosen to match the HPE/Dell names, which I would not have known. Since variable names can be anything, Still, it;s not a PowerShell code issue, but how to make certreq read that and your SANS as you are after. Not something I've needed to do with certreq. So, hummmmm......

Comment: I spent some time digging at these multiple SAN entries and it just appears the certreq.exe does not provide a way of doing without the use of an .inf file.